# method is executing before ajax call getting completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to call a method after all ajax calls gets completed but some reason the method id getting triggered before one of the ajax call is getting completed. i tried to keep the method in ajax complete section and using $.when() and async:false but i am getting same result. I don't know if its because i am using jsonp ?

My jquery version is 1.11.0

Below is my code

```
function getBBTrending() {
    bbProductD = [];
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "crazycalls/getbbtrending.php",
        // cache must be true
        cache: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
            bbTrending = data.results;
            for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                getProductdetails(bbTrending[i].productLink);
            }
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

function getProductdetails(pLink) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: pLink,
        // cache must be true
        cache: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function (data) {
            pushArray(bbProductD, data);
        },
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
}




function pushArray(array1,data1)
{
    array1.push(data1);
}

// this function is executing before pushArray(array1,data1)
jQuery( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
 displayProducts(bbProductD);
})
function displayProducts(bbProductD)
{
    jQuery("#bbButtongroup").show();
    var rProducts = bbProductD; 
    var rating;
    var html = ['<div class="row">']
    for (var i = 0; i < rProducts.length; i++)
    {
           var entry = rProducts[i];
           var title = entry.name
           var Tnail = entry.image;
           var sPrice = entry.salePrice;
           var rPrice = entry.regularPrice;
         var hcode = '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4"><div class="thumbnail"><img style="height: 200px; width: 100%; display: block;" src=\" '+ Tnail + '\" alt="..."><div class="caption"><h3 style="font-size: 14px;">'+ title +'</h3><p><span class="label label-info"> Regular Price : '+ rPrice +'</span></p><p><span style="float: right;" class="label label-info">Sale Price :'+ sPrice +'</span></p><p><a href=\"' + entry.url + '\" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Buy</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">View</a></p></div></div></div>';
         html.push(hcode);
     }
     html.push('</div>');
     document.getElementById('pContainer').innerHTML = html.join('');
}
```

this is how i added using $.when

```
jQuery.when( { getBBTrending(),getProductdetails()}).done(function() {
   displayProducts(bbProductD);
});
```

any advice?

Comment: You can't have `async: false` with JSON. But what is getting triggered too early? And why don't you not just put all the code in one AJAX call?

Comment: Don't rely on ajaxStop for that kind of work. Can't you put the ```displayProducts(bbProductD);``` call right after the ```pushArray(bbProductD,data);``` call ?

Comment: show how you tried to use `$.when`, it should do what you want

Comment: @Putvande I tried to put all the code in ajax call after forloop in getBBTrending() but it`s still the same result.

Comment: @Volune i am building my array with all the products listings than i want to call displayProducts(bbProductD) , I don`t want to call displayProducts(bbProductD) for each product.Please see i added displayProducts(bbProductD) in my original post

Comment: @charlietfl added the code to my original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asynchronous way, using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library

```
function getBBTrending() {
    bbProductD = [];
    jQuery.ajax({
        //stuff...
        success: function (data) {
            bbTrending = data.results;
            async.each(bbTrending, function(element, callback){
                getProductdetails(element.productLink, callback);
            }, function(err){
                displayProducts(bbProductD);
            });
        },
    });
}

function getProductdetails(pLink, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        //stuff
        success: function (data) {
            pushArray(bbProductD, data);
            callback(null);
        },
    });
}
```

---

The promises way, using [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) and [jQuery.when](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
function getBBTrending() {
    bbProductD = [];
    jQuery.ajax({
        //stuff...
        success: function (data) {
            bbTrending = data.results;
            var promises = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < bbTrending.length; i++) {
                var promise = getProductdetails(bbTrending[i].productLink);
                promises.push(promise);
            }
            jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, promises).then(function(){
                displayProducts(bbProductD);
            });
        },
    });
}

function getProductdetails(pLink) {
    var promise = jQuery.Deferred();
    jQuery.ajax({
        //stuff
        success: function (data) {
            pushArray(bbProductD, data);
            promise.resolve();
        },
    });
    return promise;
}
```

---

The dirty way. I do not recommend this solution, it has many flaws. Try to use libraries when you need to do asynchronous stuff in order to keep your code maintainable.

```
var queriesCount, finishedQueriesCount;

function getBBTrending() {
    bbProductD = [];
    jQuery.ajax({
        //stuff...
        success: function (data) {
            bbTrending = data.results;
            queriesCount = 0;
            finishedQueriesCount = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < bbTrending.length; i++) {
                getProductdetails(bbTrending[i].productLink);
            }
        },
    });
}

function getProductdetails(pLink) {
    queriesCount++;
    jQuery.ajax({
        //stuff
        success: function (data) {
            pushArray(bbProductD, data);
            finishedQueriesCount++;
            if(queriesCount == finishedQueriesCount) {
                displayProducts(bbProductD);
            }
        },
    });
}
```

---

In each case, I pleaced the part of your code that is not significant for the answer by `//stuff`

**Warning** This answer has no error handling, it will fail (never call `displayProducts(bbProductD);`) if you have an ajax error.

Comment: Thanks , promises way worked for me , i will keep this method in mind for future uses too.